# Uncaught Error: Cannot call abstract method (PHP Fatal error)

Tags: php, abstract-class, fatal-error

I am extending a abstract class that has two abstract methods.
When I try to instantiate the the child class, I get following error,

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot call abstract method GetAnswer::GetAnswer()
```

When I comment out the `GetAnswer()` in both parent and child things work fine.

PHP version: 7.0.2 in XAMPP, running on Wondows 8.1.

Parent class file app-getAnswer-base.php is as follows

```
<?php
abstract class GetAnswer{
    abstract public function GetAnswer($Username, $QuestionnaireID, $QuestionID);
    abstract public function GetAnswers($Username, $QuestionnaireID);
}
```

Child class file `app-getAnswer-db-direct.php` is as follows

```
<?php
require_once 'config-db-login.php';
require_once 'app-getAnswer-base.php';

class GetAnswer_SQLSelect extends GetAnswer {

    public function GetAnswer($Username, $QuestionnaireID, $QuestionID){
        return null;
    }    

    public function GetAnswers($Username, $QuestionnaireID){
        $connection = new mysqli(dbLogin::$db_hostname, dbLogin::$db_username, dbLogin::$db_password, dbLogin::$db_database);

        if ($connection->connect_error) die($connection->connect_error);

        $query = "SELECT `QuestionID`, `Answer` FROM `answerstore`.`answers` AS a JOIN  `answerstore`.`participants` AS b ON a.`ParticipantID` = b.`ParticipantID` WHERE a.`QuestionnaireID` = '$QuestionnaireID' AND b.`Username`='$Username'";

        $result = $connection->query($query);
        $connection->close();

        return $result;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you make the call that throws the error.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets, is is `$getAnswers = new GetAnswer_SQLSelect();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think when you are trying to instantiate the Child class it's calling the `GetAnswer()` method from the Parent class (`GetAnswer`) as it's working like a constructor.

Try changing the method name to something else.

Answer (score -1):

You have to instantiate the concrete class 'GetAnswer_SQLSelect' and then call the method 'GetAnswer'.

```
$GetAnswer_SQLSelect = new GetAnswer_SQLSelect(); //create new instance.
$GetAnswer_SQLSelect->GetAnswer($param1, $param2, $param3); //invoke method.
```

Comment: Then the possible issue is the one you referenced at your reply.